# ParsePy: how to delete file

Tags: python, parsing, parsepy

I'm using ParsePy (https://github.com/milesrichardson/ParsePy) and now I'm having a problem with File delete.

```
from parse_rest.datatypes import Object, File

class GameScore(Object):
    pass

with open('/path/to/screenshot.png', 'rb') as fh:
    rawdata = fh.read()

screenshotFile = File('arbitraryNameOfFile', rawdata, 'image/png')
screenshotFile.save()

gs = GameScore.Query.get(objectId='xxxxxxx')
gs.screenshot = screenshotFile
gs.save()

#
# In another function
#
class GameScore(Object):
    pass

gs = GameScore.Query.get(objectId='xxxxxxx')
gs.screenshot.delete()

# Error: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.
Loris

Comment: Looks like the server answered with invalid JSON. You should debug the response using curl and see answer from the server: `curl -X DELETE 
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" 
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: ${MASTER_KEY}" 
  https://YOUR.PARSE-SERVER.HERE/parse/files/arbitaryNameOfFile.png`. Name of your file may have prefix to avoid name collisions. To get real file name use `gs.screenshot.name`

Comment: File deleted without response by curl. In my opinion this is the problem! Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What was a response status? If it was 200, than it's a client bug, which expects JSON, but must only check a response status. The question is why only you experience such a problem? Do you have either old client or an old server? Consider to post an issue in the Github repository of parsepy.